# custom id in gremlin_python

Tags: python, graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop

A custom id can be supplied to a new vertex at the Gremlin Console as follows:

```
gremlin> g.addV('person').property(id, 1234).next()
==>v[1234]
```

In the Java client it can be done as follows:

```
graph.addVertex(T.id, customId);
```

(Where T is *org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.T*)

Is there an equivalent of *T.id* for gremlin_python to facilitate the above form?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a `T` enum for Python at `gremlin_python.process.traversal.T` ([source code](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/034a3be7bbdbb2dc8adc09679c2f6be0d34298bf/gremlin-python/src/main/jython/gremlin_python/process/traversal.py#L174))